# Checkbox / Cell link with multiple userforms

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, checkbox

I am having difficulties understanding the VBA methods of coding (I only have R experience). I am trying to link the value of a userform checkbox to a specific cell in a worksheet using VBA.

```
Sub x()
    Dim Range As Range

    If userfrom.checkbox1.Value = True Then
        Range.Offset(0, 7).Value = 1
    Else
        Range.Offset(0, 7).Value = ""
    End If


    If userform.checkbox2.Value = True Then
        Range.Offset(0, 8).Value = 1
    Else
        Range.Offset(0, 8).Value = ""
    End If


    If userform.checkbox3.Value = True Then
        Range.Offset(0, 9).Value = 1
    Else
        Range.Offset(0, 9).Value = ""
    End If

    Unload userform

End Sub
```

I have come across the method of allocating checkboxes to arrays, but am unable to understand the example in the threads.  Ideally, what I imagine doing is to declare an array of check boxes as well as an array of cells - and link each element in each array together, i.e. checkboxArray(1) -> cellArray(1); checkboxArray(2) -> cellArray(2); etc.

A colleague of mine examined my code and said that it can be made better, i.e. completed in one line.

Is this achievable?

Comment: In my opinion its homework

Comment: you can just set the cell value of the checkbox in the checkbox properties by setting the ControlSource to the cell you want.

Comment: It is more out of curiosity.  The workbook we are working on is quite large and resource intensive.  I guess it is a matter of making the code more efficient as we may need to make further modifications in the future, and preserving resources at this stage.  (I also anticipate that he is trying to show off that he knows more than I do). Personally, I do not see how this way would make to code less efficient. @ Poof - No this is not homework. @ Scott Holtzman - That would be the method for working on checkboxes placed in the worksheet, not in user forms.

Comment: No, it works on userforms as well, just the way I described. Setting the control source will set the value of the checkbox to the defined cell.

Comment: @ Scott Holtzman - Yes, you are right. Sincere apologies.  But I do require dynamic functionality, so I did not consider this option as viable at the start.  Your code works great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the ControlSource of the Checkbox to a predefined cell in your worksheet and do away with the code altogether.

However, if you need it be dynamic, based on the worksheet or range you are working with, here is a functional, efficient solution that does not depend on the number of checkboxes on the form and is easy to update.

Btw, I don't know if it **actually can be completed in one line**. All the integer counting was obtained from the code in your OP.

```
Sub x()

Dim c As Control

For Each c In Controls

    If TypeName(c) = "CheckBox" Then

        i = Replace(c.Name, "CheckBox", "")

        If c.Value = True Then SetRange i + 6, 1 Else: SetRange i + 6, ""

    End If

Next

End Sub

Sub SetRange(i As Integer, sVal As String)

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change to your sheet

With wks

    .Range("A1").Offset(, i).Value = sVal 'change "A1" to desired range

End With

End Sub
```